# SQL Between Dates Syntax

Tags: sql, date, between

I have a query that needs to return records where the ShipDate is between a range of dates.  The following query works:

```
$query = "SELECT ECCustomerOrder.ShipDate, 
ECCustomers.Customer, 
ECCustomerOrder.PO, 
ECCustomerOrder.TotalCases, 
ECCustomerOrder.order_number
FROM ECCustomerOrder INNER JOIN ECCustomers ON ECCustomerOrder.ID = ECCustomers.ID
WHERE ECCustomerOrder.ShipDate >= $todayMinus";
```

$todayMinus is a php variable set earlier in the script that takes the current date and subtracts 15 days.  What I can't get to work is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT ECCustomerOrder.ShipDate, 
ECCustomers.Customer, 
ECCustomerOrder.PO, 
ECCustomerOrder.TotalCases, 
ECCustomerOrder.order_number
FROM ECCustomerOrder INNER JOIN ECCustomers ON ECCustomerOrder.ID = ECCustomers.ID
WHERE ECCustomerOrder.ShipDate BETWEEN $todayMinus AND $todayPlus";
```

What is the proper syntax for this SQL query to return the records between the ShipDates of $todayMinus and $todayPlus?

Comment: Is this MySQL?, do you need to include results for today?, why is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you're using plain dates, you'll have to quote them.

e.g.

```
ShipDate BETWEEN 2013-01-01 AND 2013-02-19
```

is incorrect, because `2013-01-01` is a substraction, you're actually doing

```
ShipDate BETWEEN 2011 AND 1992
```

try

```
ShipDate BETWEEN '$todayMinus' AND '$todayPlus'
```

Comment: That's all it took, Marc.  Thanks for the tip.